# My system is being attacked or it is attacking

Tags: antivirus, smb

My system is running on Windows 10. I am using Avast Free Antivirus. Today i got an update from Windows update. After installing that update Avast started raising notification saying

> We've safely aborted connection on because it was infected with **smb:cve-2017-0144[Expl].**

The detailed notification is shown in the in the image.

[image: The notification by Avast]

The IP 192.168.114.50 belongs to my LAN. The IP of my system is 192.168.114.72. I want to know if my system is attacking 192.168.114.50 or it is being attacked by 192.168.114.50.

I am confused because of url. I searched Avast Forums but could not get an explanation but a suggestion to block port 445. It confused me more by suspecting my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the alert you have windows file sharing turned on(CIFS) and another machine 114.50 tried to connect and use an exploit related to CVE-2017-0144 . It would appear from the alert 114.50 is infected, run your AV/cleaner on that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain the url? I mean it looks like my system is asking for smb://192.168.114.50/nsa:cve-2017-0144_EternalBlue.